# AWK split string

Tags: bash, awk

I need to split following string into two parts in `AWK`. below line is one line.

`Dec 10 03:38:49 cgnat1.dd.com  1 2015 Dec 9 14:38:47 02-g4-adsl - - NAT44 - [UserbasedW - 100.70.92.248 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.125 - 38912 39935 - - ]`

`Dec 10 03:38:52 cgnat2.dd.com  1 2015 Dec 9 14:38:51 01-g2-adsl - - NAT44 - [UserbasedW - 100.70.21.77 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.42 - 1024 2047 - - ][UserbasedW - 100.70.21.36 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.38 - 64512 65535 - - ]`

First part:

`Dec 10 03:38:49 cgnat1.dd.com  1 2015 Dec 9 14:38:47 02-g4-adsl - - NAT44 -`

Second part:

`[UserbasedW - 100.70.92.248 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.125 - 38912 39935 - - ]`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `awk '$14=$14"\n"' file`

Comment: what did you try? what is the pattern to split lines?

Comment: `sed 's/\[/\n&/' file` ?

Comment: are you trying to split starting from `[`? In that case you could use `awk -F '[' '{print "Part1: "$1 "\nPart2: "$2}' `

Comment: This is one line 

`Dec 10 03:38:49 cgnat1.dd.com  1 2015 Dec 9 14:38:47 02-g4-adsl - - NAT44 - [UserbasedW - 100.70.92.248 vrf-testnet - 222.222.34.125 - 38912 39935 - - ]`

I need to devide this into two parts.

Comment: again: what is the pattern to split lines?

Comment: this is the separator "- ["

Comment: you just have this one line and you want to split only once? If not, then please specify the pattern/delimiter

Comment: @Hemang note with this you "loose" the `[`, so you may want to say `print FS, $2`.

Comment: @fedorqui Yes I missed that, but you've covered it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk -F '[' '{print $1 "\n" FS $2}'`